# How do I set a cell background colour based on its contents using PHP after reading values from MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have this code reading values from a MySQL DB.

I've fiddled with classes in css to style the table cell backgrounds - but can't see how to do it in this case. It's almost like the php gets in the way - but I need it to read the results!!

The 'grades' in each variable will only ever be 1,2,3 or 4.

Any ideas?

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['si_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['att_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['pro_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['qot_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['qoe_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
  }?>
```

Eventually, I want a 'set of coloured cells'...

Comment: Use an if statement and based on its condition change the inline CSS code that control the background color :)

Comment: So in wich case you want a cell `bgcolor='whatever'` ?

Comment: Can you show the CSS you tried?

Comment: so you want a different color for each grade? meaning Grade1 = green, Grade2=lightgreen, Grade3-=lime...  or do you want colors for each type of grade, meaning green for all "pro_grades", lightgreen for all "quo_grade"...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a CSS class based on the values and use that

```
.val1 { background-color: red; }
.val2 { background-color: blue; }
# etc
```

Then you do this in the PHP code

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="val'.$row['si_grade'].'">'.$row['si_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="val'.$row['att_grade'].'">'.$row['att_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="val'.$row['pro_grade'].'">'.$row['pro_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="val'.$row['qot_grade'].'">'.$row['qot_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="val'.$row['qoe_grade'].'">'.$row['qoe_grade'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
  }?>
```

Comment: I didn't think to append the .$row['si_grade'] bit to the class="val

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a go. I was thinking 'if' but couldn't figure out where to fit it in!

Comment: Works like a dream. Thanks. And thanks for making me open my eyes - I was obsessed with looking for a conditional in there!

Answer (score 0):

The information from the database (1,2,3,4) will populate as data inside the cells of the table.  What you want is to put it in the `class` of the `<td>` like such:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class='.$row['si_grade'].'></td>';
    echo '<td class='.$row['att_grade'].'></td>';
    echo '<td class='.$row['pro_grade'].'></td>';
    echo '<td class='.$row['qot_grade'].'></td>';
    echo '<td class='.$row['qoe_grade'].'></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Edited to Add: Machavity's answer also gives the value in the cell, mine only colors the cell.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. I'll be adding css to the class to colour the text too (I can choose whether I want it to show or not at a later date!)